# Add labels for each data point in a plot

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am having some issues with plotting my clusters in R. 
I am using Kmeans as a way of compressing my dataset. 
My dataset is already labeled into 10 classes, so i already know what class each datapoint belongs to.  Is it possible to visualize how each datapoint is sorted within each cluster. Such that I could make some form of conclusion of the class distribution within each cluster.

I tried using table

```
table(data$labels[kmeans_output$clusterr==1])
```

which outputs

```
C0  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9 
  4   0   0   1   0  13   0   0 245   0
```

Which i think is the class distribution of cluster 1.

Is possible to visualize this for all the clusters?

[image]

Comment: That does not look like clustering worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using `iris` as your example is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).
Is this what you're looking for?

```
km <- kmeans(iris[, 1:2], 3)
plot(iris[, 1:2], col=km$cluster)
table(iris$Species, km$cluster)
```

Comment: how would you plot it, i am using 30 clusters or more so plotting it would be a bit dense. bet yes table works.

Comment: well, any plotting approach on the same graph would likely superimpose all informations..

Comment: maybe a confusion matrix would be a better display?

Comment: the table is different sized.. so ordinary confusiomatrix won't work

Comment: you mean some levels are missing?

Comment: i think `image.plot` seems to fit.. but labels aren't accurate